# NTLM-Authentication prompted 3 Times - > Windows Netlogon?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, windows-authentication, ntlm

After a few weeks I unregularily have Problems with the User-Authentication in SharePoint. The Username and password field prompted 3 Times and after that only a Server Restart can fix it for a few days. For Authentification I use NTLM. In Event Viewer it shows me Netlogon Problems 5719. I searched after Netlogon and only find the solution to fill The registry with Dword maxconcurrentapi without success.

Technical facts:
SharePoint foundation 2013 runs on its own Server with Windows Server 2012 Standard. The Active Directory and Domaincontroller is based on a Windows Server 2008 R2.